# Inherit properties from customized abstract ActionBeanInfo class possible?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to inherit properties from a customized abstract *ActionBeanInfo*-class to implementation classes? Lets say there is an abstract class which define a property like the variable name an all the descritions and bean validations. Now there should be another class which extends these class with other properties. I expected that the description of all properties where display correctly in the IDE but it isn't. It displays only the property names without the defined description and category etc. So is it possible to inherit properties to other classes?

Comment: I don't understand. BeanInfo and Action classses are two different inheritance hierarchies. Do you mean to derive one BeanInfo from another BeanInfo? That is possible.

Comment: The case is one class like `abstract class MyBeanInfo extends ActionBeanInfo` and an inherit class like `public class ImplBeanInfo extends MyBeanInfo`. `MyBeanInfo` is the BeanInfo class for an abstract action class implementation and `ImplBeanInfo` the correspondend BeanInfo class to the inherited implementation of the action bean. Now I expected that the property-descriptions of the `MyBeanInfo`also are inherited to the `ImplBeanInfo` and are displayed correctly at the IDE. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, we use that a lot for the standard beans in install4j. Maybe you can show some code for the bean info classes, then I can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I will check the code again. Maybe there is a bug in it. Is there a log file for the IDE where I can get informations about it?

Comment: You can look at %TEMP%\install4j_error.log. It is created if there is output on stderr.